# SSLHandshakeException SSLProtocolExceptionL SSL handshake aborted SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_cInt.c

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp, tls1.2

We have just migrated our web api to a new server and are now getting problems with our Android 4.4.2 devices that try to connect to it.

According to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html, our site has only TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 available. (The same page also says "This site works only in browsers with SNI support", but I'm not sure if that's an issue.)

So I have tried (successfully?) to ensure TLS 1.2 is the only protocol enabled in the Android app.

However, I get this stacktrace when trying to connect:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5c7a4dd0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1407742E:SSL
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_cInt.c:744 0x5db246ed:0x00000000)
```

This is the part of my Android app that tries to connect to the web service:

```
    try {
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
        }
        X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
    
//SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

//sslContext.init(null, null, null);
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) { // <= 19 (Android 4.4)
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Using custom NoSSLv3SocketFactory");
            sslSocketFactory = new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
        }
        else {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Using default Socket Factory");
            sslSocketFactory = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
        }
        builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not set SSL socket factory", e);
        Utilities.makeToast(this, "Could not set SSL socket factory: " + e);
        Utilities.doAcra(this, e);
    }

    client = builder.build();
    //...
    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

And here is the NoSSLv3SocketFactory class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedListener;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class NoSSLv3SocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory{

    private final static String TAG = NoSSLv3SocketFactory.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static String SSL_v3 = "SSLv3";
    private final static String TLS_v1_1 = "TLSv1.1";
    private final static String TLS_v1_2 = "TLSv1.2";
    private final static String TLS_v1_3 = "TLSv1.3";

    private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

    public NoSSLv3SocketFactory() {
        this.delegate = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
    }

    public NoSSLv3SocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    private Socket makeSocketSafe(Socket socket) {
        if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
            socket = new NoSSLv3SSLSocket((SSLSocket) socket);
            ((NoSSLv3SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{ TLS_v1_2});
        }
        return socket;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private class NoSSLv3SSLSocket extends DelegateSSLSocket {

        private NoSSLv3SSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
            super(delegate);

        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
//            if (protocols != null && protocols.length == 1 && SSL_v3.equals(protocols[0])) {
//
//                List<String> enabledProtocols = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(delegate.getEnabledProtocols()));
//                if (enabledProtocols.size() > 1) {
//                    enabledProtocols.remove(SSL_v3);
//                    System.out.println("Removed SSLv3 from enabled protocols");
//                } else {
//                    System.out.println("SSL stuck with protocol available for " + String.valueOf(enabledProtocols));
//                }
//                protocols = enabledProtocols.toArray(new String[enabledProtocols.size()]);
//            }

            if (protocols != null) {

                List<String> enabledProtocols = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(delegate.getEnabledProtocols()));

                // Remove SSL3
                if (enabledProtocols.contains(SSL_v3)) {
                    enabledProtocols.remove(SSL_v3);
                    System.out.println("Removed SSLv3 from enabled protocols");
                }

                // Add TLS1.2
                if (!enabledProtocols.contains(TLS_v1_2)) {
                    enabledProtocols.add(TLS_v1_2);
                }

                protocols = enabledProtocols.toArray(new String[enabledProtocols.size()]);
            }
            else {

                // Create with TLS1.2 only
                protocols = new String[] {TLS_v1_2};
            }

            super.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
        }
    }

    public class DelegateSSLSocket extends SSLSocket {

        protected final SSLSocket delegate;

        DelegateSSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
            return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getEnabledCipherSuites() {
            return delegate.getEnabledCipherSuites();
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabledCipherSuites(String[] suites) {
            delegate.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getSupportedProtocols() {
            return delegate.getSupportedProtocols();
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getEnabledProtocols() {
            return delegate.getEnabledProtocols();
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
            delegate.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
        }

        @Override
        public SSLSession getSession() {
            return delegate.getSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void addHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener listener) {
            delegate.addHandshakeCompletedListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener listener) {
            delegate.removeHandshakeCompletedListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void startHandshake() throws IOException {
            delegate.startHandshake();
        }

        @Override
        public void setUseClientMode(boolean mode) {
            delegate.setUseClientMode(mode);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getUseClientMode() {
            return delegate.getUseClientMode();
        }

        @Override
        public void setNeedClientAuth(boolean need) {
            delegate.setNeedClientAuth(need);
        }

        @Override
        public void setWantClientAuth(boolean want) {
            delegate.setWantClientAuth(want);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getNeedClientAuth() {
            return delegate.getNeedClientAuth();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getWantClientAuth() {
            return delegate.getWantClientAuth();
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnableSessionCreation(boolean flag) {
            delegate.setEnableSessionCreation(flag);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getEnableSessionCreation() {
            return delegate.getEnableSessionCreation();
        }

        @Override
        public void bind(SocketAddress localAddr) throws IOException {
            delegate.bind(localAddr);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
            delegate.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr) throws IOException {
            delegate.connect(remoteAddr);
        }

        @Override
        public void connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr, int timeout) throws IOException {
            delegate.connect(remoteAddr, timeout);
        }

        @Override
        public SocketChannel getChannel() {
            return delegate.getChannel();
        }

        @Override
        public InetAddress getInetAddress() {
            return delegate.getInetAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return delegate.getInputStream();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getKeepAlive() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getKeepAlive();
        }

        @Override
        public InetAddress getLocalAddress() {
            return delegate.getLocalAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public int getLocalPort() {
            return delegate.getLocalPort();
        }

        @Override
        public SocketAddress getLocalSocketAddress() {
            return delegate.getLocalSocketAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getOOBInline() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getOOBInline();
        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            return delegate.getOutputStream();
        }

        @Override
        public int getPort() {
            return delegate.getPort();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized int getReceiveBufferSize() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getReceiveBufferSize();
        }

        @Override
        public SocketAddress getRemoteSocketAddress() {
            return delegate.getRemoteSocketAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getReuseAddress() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getReuseAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized int getSendBufferSize() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getSendBufferSize();
        }

        @Override
        public int getSoLinger() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getSoLinger();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized int getSoTimeout() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getSoTimeout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getTcpNoDelay() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getTcpNoDelay();
        }

        @Override
        public int getTrafficClass() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getTrafficClass();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isBound() {
            return delegate.isBound();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isClosed() {
            return delegate.isClosed();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isConnected() {
            return delegate.isConnected();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isInputShutdown() {
            return delegate.isInputShutdown();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isOutputShutdown() {
            return delegate.isOutputShutdown();
        }

        @Override
        public void sendUrgentData(int value) throws IOException {
            delegate.sendUrgentData(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void setKeepAlive(boolean keepAlive) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setKeepAlive(keepAlive);
        }

        @Override
        public void setOOBInline(boolean oobinline) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setOOBInline(oobinline);
        }

        @Override
        public void setPerformancePreferences(int connectionTime, int latency, int bandwidth) {
            delegate.setPerformancePreferences(connectionTime, latency, bandwidth);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void setReceiveBufferSize(int size) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setReceiveBufferSize(size);
        }

        @Override
        public void setReuseAddress(boolean reuse) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setReuseAddress(reuse);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void setSendBufferSize(int size) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setSendBufferSize(size);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSoLinger(boolean on, int timeout) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setSoLinger(on, timeout);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void setSoTimeout(int timeout) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        }

        @Override
        public void setTcpNoDelay(boolean on) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setTcpNoDelay(on);
        }

        @Override
        public void setTrafficClass(int value) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setTrafficClass(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void shutdownInput() throws IOException {
            delegate.shutdownInput();
        }

        @Override
        public void shutdownOutput() throws IOException {
            delegate.shutdownOutput();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return delegate.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return delegate.equals(o);
        }
    }

}
```

Because the app has to run on Android 4.4.2, it is using the latest compatible library:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.2'
```

Also, we don't have any of the Google APIs available as it's a proprietary device.

I've seen so many related questions on SO, but none of the suggestions I've tried have worked.

Unless there's something I've missed or got wrong in the Android code, is there something I could do regarding the server configuration that could fix the problem?

For completeness, here is the rest of the output from the **Configuration** section of our ssllabs results page:

```
**Protocols**
TLS 1.3 Yes
TLS 1.2 Yes*
TLS 1.1 No
TLS 1.0 No
SSL 3   No
SSL 2   No
(*) Experimental: Server negotiated using No-SNI


****Cipher Suites****
# TLS 1.3 (server has no preference)
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  128
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  256
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256
**# TLS 1.2 (server has no preference)**
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)   ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS 256

**Handshake Simulation**
Android 4.4.2   RSA 2048 (SHA256)   TLS 1.2 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384   ECDH secp521r1  FS


**Protocol Details**
DROWN   No, server keys and hostname not seen elsewhere with SSLv2
(1) For a better understanding of this test, please read this longer explanation
(2) Key usage data kindly provided by the Censys network search engine; original DROWN website here
(3) Censys data is only indicative of possible key and certificate reuse; possibly out-of-date and not complete
Secure Renegotiation    Supported
Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation   No
Insecure Client-Initiated Renegotiation No
BEAST attack    Mitigated server-side (more info)  
POODLE (SSLv3)  No, SSL 3 not supported (more info)
POODLE (TLS)    No (more info)
Zombie POODLE   No (more info)   TLS 1.2 : 0xc027
GOLDENDOODLE    No (more info)   TLS 1.2 : 0xc027
OpenSSL 0-Length    No (more info)   TLS 1.2 : 0xc027
Sleeping POODLE No (more info)   TLS 1.2 : 0xc027
Downgrade attack prevention Yes, TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV supported (more info)
SSL/TLS compression No
RC4 No
Heartbeat (extension)   No
Heartbleed (vulnerability)  No (more info)
Ticketbleed (vulnerability) No (more info)
OpenSSL CCS vuln. (CVE-2014-0224)   No (more info)
OpenSSL Padding Oracle vuln.
(CVE-2016-2107) No (more info)
ROBOT (vulnerability)   No (more info)
Forward Secrecy Yes (with most browsers)   ROBUST (more info)
ALPN    Yes   h2 http/1.1
NPN No
Session resumption (caching)    Yes
Session resumption (tickets)    Yes
OCSP stapling   Yes
Strict Transport Security (HSTS)    No
HSTS Preloading Not in: Chrome  Edge  Firefox  IE 
Public Key Pinning (HPKP)   No (more info)
Public Key Pinning Report-Only  No
Public Key Pinning (Static) No (more info)
Long handshake intolerance  No
TLS extension intolerance   No
TLS version intolerance No
Incorrect SNI alerts    No
Uses common DH primes   No, DHE suites not supported
DH public server param (Ys) reuse   No, DHE suites not supported
ECDH public server param reuse  No
Supported Named Groups  secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x25519, x448 (Server has no preference)
SSL 2 handshake compatibility   No
0-RTT enabled   No
```

Comment: Just for reference: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2372

Comment: @MorrisonChang That's a massive help, thank you.